# Angular5 data prepopulation one way binding not happening

Tags: angular5

I am using a parent component travelerInput that creates travelerListForm using model in my component and iterate it extracting travelerForm which is then passed to the nested child components using `@Input`:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfTravelers; i++) {
  const tId = `${ptc}_0${i}`;
  const Id = `${TravelerInput.pIndex++}`;
  const traveler = new Traveler({passengerTypeCode: ptc, id: Id, tid: tId, names: [new Identity({
    firstName: "",
    middleName: "",
    lastName: "",
    title: "",
    nameType: "native",
    isDisplayed: false
    })],
  dateOfBirth: undefined ,
  gender: "unknown",
  accompanyingTravelerId: "",
  accompanyingTravelerTid: ""
});
travelerList.push(traveler);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="alpi-section col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"
      *ngFor="let travelerForm of travelerListForm.controls; let tIndex = index;">

      <o3r-simple-traveler-input 
      [config]="config.simpleTravelerInput"
      [travelerForm]="travelerForm"
      [index]="tIndex">          
      </o3r-simple-traveler-input>
```

Now we have a drop down in parent component with a list of travelers. The selected passenger in the drop down will have its information prepopulated in the form fields which are nested child components. I am using travelerForm which is iterated over travelerListForm in child components as `@Input`. On change of drop down I am binding the value of the passenger information to the corresponding index of travelerListForm which is also getting updated but on UI there is no update.

```
 pickSelectedADTPassenger(adult:any, index: number){

      this.selectedADTId= this.ADTTravelerId[adult];

    this.travelerListForm.controls[index].value.names[0].firstName = this.selectedADTId.IDENTITY_INFORMATION.FIRST_NAME; //ASSISGNMENT

    }
```

Have also tried using **ngModel** in the child component input field where I want the value to be prepopulated but it did not work:

```
<input type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="travelerForm.controls.firstName.value"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="FIRST NAME"
            maxlength="52"
            formControlName="firstName">
 </div>
```

Please suggest.